# Merge 2D List if duplicate

Tags: python, list

My actual list looks like:

```
[192, 25]
[192, 50]
[193, 13]
[195, 3]
[195, 5]
```

And I want merge the duplicate numbers of my list. The first index in should not change as value, the second one should be added. So that it looks like:

```
[192, 75]
[193, 13]
[195, 8]
```

Comment: Please show the code that you tried, it will be much helpful then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary, and call `dict.get` with default value `0` and keep on adding the second value for each first value, finally convert it back to the `list`

```py
lists = [[192, 25],
[192, 50],
[193, 13],
[195, 3],
[195, 5]]

result = {}
for k,v in lists:
    result[k] = result.get(k,0) + v
    
list(list(item) for item in result.items())

#output
[[192, 75], [193, 13], [195, 8]]
```

Comment: What I wrote, but more concise, I prefer this one ^^

Comment: It's generally better to use `dict.get` rather than to check the existence manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Python's built-in `itertools.groupby()` which is a method groups the similar type of object into an iterator object:

```py
from itertools import groupby

lists = [[192, 25], [192, 50], [193, 13], [195, 3], [195, 5]]

output = [[k, sum(e[1] for e in v)] for k, v in groupby(lists, key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

Output:

```py
[[192, 75], [193, 13], [195, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a dict `lookup` with logic if the first element `l[0]` not exist in dict `lookup` Add it with its value `l[1]`, Otherwise means already exist So just accumulate it with its prior values. Then turn this dict into a 2d list and print it:

```py
lists = [
[192, 25],
[192, 50],
[193, 13],
[195, 3],
[195, 5]
]
lookup = {}
for l in lists:
        if l[0] not in lookup:
            lookup[l[0]] = l[1]
        else:
            lookup[l[0]] += l[1]

print([[k,v] for k,v in lookup.items()])
#[[192, 75], [193, 13], [195, 8]]
```